# With Open Liberty, how to use an environment variable as an application property?

Tags: java, spring, websphere, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I expected to be able to do something like this in my server.xml, but I could not get it to work:

```
<variable name="my.ldap.url" value="${LDAP_URL}" />
```

Setting it in jvm.options or server.env do not seem to be options either from what I can tell. Neither of those are parsing environment variables from my tests.

```
-Dmy.ldap.url=$LDAP_URL
```

Setting properties in my own files and using environment variables did not seem to work either. I tried something like this in my server.xml

```
<library id="configs">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/configs" includes="*.properties" />
</library>
```

So I'm just lost for ideas right now. How do I take environment variables and inject them into an Open Liberty application as application properties?

I searched high and low for documentation on this, with no success.

In Jboss I was able to accomplish simple via

```
bin/standalone.sh -Dmy.ldap.url=$LDAP_URL
```

Comment: Can you include some example code from your application where you're trying to use the property? If you get an error, please include that as well.

Comment: @Azquelt its just normal java.util.Properties nothing special.

Comment: Ok, but how are you reading or injecting it? Are you using `@Inject` and expecting a framework to inject it, are you trying to do `Properties.load()` and read from a classpath resource or are you doing something different?

Comment: From your edit, it looks like you're setting a system property? Are you trying to read it in your application code with `System.getProperty(name)`?

Answer (score 3):

It should work for you exactly the way it does in Jboss:

`wlp/bin/server start server1 -Dmy.ldap.url=$LDAP_URL`

Your `<variable>` definition would create a Liberty configuration variable that resolves to the value of LDAP_URL in the environment, but it would not be set as a java system property.

If you're still seeing problems with passing the value on the command line you could check all java system properties by running:

`wlp/bin/server dump {server name}`

In the output zip file, the dump_{timestamp}/introspections/JavaRuntimeInformation.txt will show both the command line arguments and all defined java system properties.

Comment: I think this solves it. I also found the <appProperties> tag that seems to work for me, since you can use environment variables in the server.xml ...
https://openliberty.io/guides/microprofile-config-intro.html#configuring-as-an-appproperties-element-scoped-by-application

Comment: This answer does not answer the question because it creates variables (as you said). I posted the final solution that I got working below.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using Microprofile config, checkout this [guide](https://openliberty.io/guides/microprofile-config-intro.html) and see it does answer your questions.

It shows you how to inject variables using following schema:

```
@Inject @ConfigProperty(name="port")
private int port;
```

assuming there is PORT env entry in your system.

You can also use env variables in server configuration using `server.xml` for example:

```
<properties.db2.jcc serverName="${JDBC_HOST}" portNumber="${JDBC_PORT}" databaseName="${JDBC_DB}" sslConnection="${JDBC_SSL}"
            user="${JDBC_ID}" password="${JDBC_PASSWORD}"/>
```

Details here https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/reference/config/server-configuration-overview.html

For your library point you would have to add it to your application via classloader, so I wouldn't recommend that. Like this:

```
<application name="myapp" type="ear" location="myapp.ear">
  <classloader commonLibraryRef="configs" />
</application>
```

Hope it solves your problems.

Comment: I need a solution that does not involve modifying code. Nothing in here is helpful to me.

Comment: @RbC So show us your code, as we cannot guess what are you doing.

Comment: If it's truly environment variables, vs. like JVM `-D` system properties, the server.xml syntax above - same as in your question - does that without code changes. Or, in earlier versions of Liberty, use `${env.VARIABLE}`. This is also stated in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

The final answer I found to this, is you can inject environment variables into properties using the `<appProperties>` tag in your server.xml

Documentation is here
https://openliberty.io/guides/microprofile-config-intro.html#configuring-as-an-appproperties-element-scoped-by-application

A simple example of this using an environment variable looks like ...

```
<webApplication location="my.war" type="war">
  <appProperties>
     <property name="my.ldap.url" value="${LDAP_URL}"/>
  </appProperties>
</webApplication>
```